# Calling a stored procedure using Entity Framework Error

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have an error when trying to attempt to call a store procedure i n c# using ADO.Net Entity Framework, The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'EmbraceModel1.Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result'. A member of the type, 'Error', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

I have generated the POCO class using Entity Framework and code generation added functions and Complex types, my complex type named Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result gets generated with the properties 'ST_Key' and 'Error' but when I test it cannot resolve the column named 'Error'. When I look at the store procedure in SSMS it has a result-set different from the auto-generated result, it has four Columns, St_Key, Supplier_Claim, Orig_Inv, and System_Cost, the response is dynamic based on what values you pass, it may return just an St-key and Supplier_Claim, or just a System_Cost, could this be why it return this error, this is when I test in a WCF test client, when I test it in a console application it just restuns a negative 1(-1) and no value at all. Below is my code

```
public Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result ExcludeFailedValidationRecords(string lineNumber, decimal totalClaim)
    {
        using (EmbraceEntities4 context = new EmbraceEntities4())
        {
            var claims = context.Supplier_Claim_Upload(lineNumber, totalClaim);
            return new Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result();
        }

    }
```

This is the auto generated Result Set by Entity Framework

```
public partial class Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result
{
    public string ST_Key { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
}
```

The column Error doesn't appear when I run Proc in SSMS, which is kind of confusing me as to why its getting generated, I tried manually adding the remainder column in my generated model class but it reruns no value when I run thorough WCF, any idea as to why this is happening

Here is how I run the Proc from SSMS

```
 USE [Embrace]
    GO

    DECLARE @return_value int

    EXEC    @return_value = [CRM].[Supplier_Claim_Upload]
            @Invoice = N'TA12146170*02-2',
            @Amount = 37.000

    SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

    GO
```

The result I get for this specific call to the PROC is

ST_Key, Supplier_Claim, Orig_Inv,   System_Cost,

TA12146170*02-2 Warning: You Are going to Overwrite a Claim Value: 32.000

this is the ST_Key value TA12146170*02-2 and the Supplier_Claim isWarning: You Are going to Overwrite a Claim Value: 32.000, there is no Error Column that is being retuned, yet EF generates the Proc result as such.

Comment: maybe its a name conflict, you could rename Error to ErrorText or ErrorMessage which is also a better name IMHO

Comment: Changing the name to anything else, returns the same error with the renamed value

Comment: Let's see the stored procedure. Do you have any other auto-generated classes? Do they have `Error` also?

Comment: JayMee, please see updated , I do not have any other auto generated classes